# Save the data entered in textfields,date picker,etc in a view(page) to a Uitableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, xcode4

i have a view(page) with lots of textfields,date pickers, etc. This page is displayed using presentModalViewController. Now i want to save the data entered in the textfields to the tableView. Each textfields in the page corresponds to the column in the tableview.

I want to save the page's data on click of a button to the tableview as row wise.

Any Help !!

Comment: use protocal to add data into array then reload table according to that array

Answer (score 0):

You could use a protocol and delegate object. Here is a simple example that will show you how to accomplish that:

http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/04/15/passing-data-between-views-tutorial-using-a-protocol-delegate-in-your-iphone-app/

Answer (score 0):

Your View is presented from a ViewController, which is Controlling the View.

On clicking the save button on the View, the ViewController can pull the data from the fields in the View, and save them into a Model object which you can then add into your UITableViewDataSource array (or whatever you have to load data into your table).

You can then tell your UITableView to update row at index path, and it will pull the new data from the datasource and update your table.

Voila....

... a cleverer (is that a word) approach would be to bind your Model properties to your View elements (from your controller), so as they are updated, the model changes. The table could be using KVO to listen for Model changes and update their view components at the same time.